# When Scanning for a Pattern, how can you check within the String for a range of floats?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

Basically, I'm attempting to pull data from a website by using an HTTP GET request. I create a scanner which looks through all of the information pulled from the GET request. My question specifically is how I can get the Scanner to recognize a range of float values within this desired pattern. The pattern is as follows:
`"<strong>`**x**`k</strong> <div class="match_details_cell_label">Gold</div>"`

The letter x above represents a float which could be in the range [0.0-50.0]. My question is how do I represent that to the Scanner. I'm familiar with how to check if an integer is within a set of values, but how do I incorporate that notion of "range" while scanning?

```
    GetGameInfo http = new GetGameInfo();

    System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
    Scanner lolscan = new Scanner(http.sendGet());
    String gameGold = 
            lolscan.next("<strong>" + [0-30] + "k</strong><div class=\"match_details_cell_label\">Gold</div>");
```

As you can see, I tried concatenating a range of acceptable values, but I don't think this is the right way to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1768232

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex for parsing HTML!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1768232

Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) or [JSoup Maven](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.jsoup|jsoup|1.7.2|jar) instead, like:

```
List<Double> doubles = new LinkedList<>();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements elem = doc.select("strong");
for(Element element : elem) { 
    try {
        doubles.add(Double.valueOf(elem.text()));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // handle it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems you have here:

1. Regular expressions are bad at parsing HTML. Just one example is that `<strong><foo/>30.0</strong>...` will fail any sensible regular expression you come up with, but should probably pass your test here. I use regexs on HTML all the time, but you should keep in mind that it's like pointing a gun at your foot and pulling the trigger when you want to show someone that it's not loaded.
2. Your code is not syntactically valid.  `Scanner#next` takes a `String` argument.
3. `[0-30]` is a character class, matching exactly one character which is one of `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`.  Probably not what you mean.

Regular expressions are a bad match for things like "numbers between 0.0 and 50.0".  It'd be better to match *all* numbers, then have Java parse them and compare them numerically.